# How to Parse received Hex bytes into readable string

Tags: c#, mifare, acr122

As the title says, I've been working on MiFare Classic reading a card.
I'm using the MiFare v1.1.3 Library from NuGet

and it returns a byte array, which I parse to readable Hex strings, by looping thru it.

Here's the code snippet:

```cs
int sector = 1;
int block = 0;
int size = 16;
var data = await localCard.GetData(sector, block, size);
string hexString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    hexString += data[i].ToString("X2") + " ";
}
// hexString returns 84 3D 17 B0 1E 08 04 00 02 63 B5 F6 B9 BE 77 1D
```

Now, how can I parse it properly?

I've tried parsing it into ASCII, ANSI, Int, Int64, Base64, Long
and all of them didn't match the 'data' that it's suppose to contain

EDIT:
The expected output: `1206058`
HEX String returned: `84 3D 17 B0 1E 08 04 00 02 63 B5 F6 B9 BE 77 1D`

Comment: Its unclear what your objectives are

Comment: I want the returned bytes to be readable

Comment: @JayzeeNSI Readable as _what_ though?  What are you expecting the response to contain?

Comment: Oh right, I'll include that in the edited post

Comment: What is the input, what is the content of the byte array?

Comment: 'HEX String returned' is the input byte converted to hex string

Comment: @Auditive that seems the case, since I cannot encode it using all encodings I know of

Comment: What if you try directly get string of `var data` by `string s = Encoding.SomeEncoding.GetString(data)`? Skipping the hex-conversion.

Comment: Tried that too, returns a garbled mess of string characters

Comment: @JayzeeNSI a 7-character string containing just digits wouldn't be converted into a byte array with 16 bytes. Even with UTF16, it would be 14 bytes and every other byte would be `00`. UTF32 would result in 28 bytes.  In *all* other encodings, `1206058` would generate 7 bytes. The binary representation of `1206058` requires just 4 bytes too. You definitely read too many bytes, but are you sure you're reading the correct bytes?

Comment: I guess its either it contains command bytes, or not the correct byte sector at all

Answer (score 1):

I've checked [the source code](https://github.com/novotnyllc/MiFare/blob/master/src/MiFare/Classic/MiFARECard.cs)

it looks like both `Task<byte[]> GetData` `Task SetData` methods do not have any special logic to transform the data. Data are just saved (and read) as `byte[]`

I suppose that you have to contact author/company that has wrote data you are trying to read.

> The expected output: 1206058

Looks strange since you are reading 16 bytes `size = 16` and expecting 7 characters to be read.

Is it possible that `block` or `sector` values are incorrect ?

Comment: I also check sources of it and didn't find any conversion from hex-strings there. Think exactly hex-string are in-use in code (like when we comparing not plain passwords, but their hashes).
In fact of unreadable `data` and impossibility to manipulate with it directly, it transforms to hex-string to be able to be compared or smth.

Comment: Among all the blocks, only the one above is what I can currently get (with values), and all other blocks/sectors contains zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

If `var data` potentially is `string` - you can reverse it from hex by:

```
// To Hex
byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MiFare v1.1.3");
string hexString = "";

for (int i = 0; i < plainBytes.Length; i++)
    hexString += plainBytes[i].ToString("X2") + " ";

Console.WriteLine(hexString); // Result: "4D 69 46 61 72 65 20 76 31 2E 31 2E 33"
        
// From Hex
hexString = hexString.Replace(" ", ""); // Remove whitespaces to have "4D69466172652076312E312E33"  
byte[] hexBytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length / 2; i++)
    hexBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(2 * i, 2), 16);

string plainString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hexBytes);    
Console.WriteLine(plainString); // Result: "MiFare v1.1.3"
```

Just, probably, should be needed to define correct Encoding.

Comment: Tried this and it returned ```„=°?=?```

Comment: Probably, we can conclude, that input `data` isn't plain text string (in byte representation), which could be easily readed. It's encoded/encrypted or not a text at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple program to solve your problem. Perhaps this is what you want to achieve:

```
// The original byte data array; some random data
byte[] data = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 85, 128, 255 };

// Byte data -> Hex string
StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();

foreach (byte item in data)
{
    hexString.Append($"{item.ToString("X2")} ");
}

Console.WriteLine(hexString.ToString().Trim());

// Hex string -> List of bytes
string[] hexArray = hexString.ToString().Trim().Split(' ');
List<byte> dataList = new List<byte>();

foreach (string item in hexArray)
{
    dataList.Add(byte.Parse(item, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
}

dataList.ForEach(b => Console.Write($"{b} "));
Console.WriteLine();
```

If it is not the right solution please provide us more info about your problem.

Comment: The question is in something like "How to get `1206058` from hex-string `84 3D 17 B0 1E 08 04 00 02 63 B5 F6 B9 BE 77 1D`?".
Converting `1206058` to hex-string doesn't gives `84 3D 17 B0 1E 08 04 00 02 63 B5 F6 B9 BE 77 1D` and converting hex-string `84 3D 17 B0 1E 08 04 00 02 63 B5 F6 B9 BE 77 1D` in known ways doesn't gives `1206058`.